# Submit button is hidden once reCAPCHA is verified

Tags: form-submit, recaptcha

Submit button on my HTML page is hidden once my reCAPTCHA is completed. This is happening only on Chrome and the same form is working perfectly in IE and Firefox.

I've checked the code and there is nothing written to hide the button.